# How to select groups of vertices in weight paint mode?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, weight-paint-mode

I've made a little model and have automatically set weights when parenting the mesh to the armature. This means I'm moving the characters hand and his head is deforming. I can select individual vertices with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left Mouse Button</kbd>, but I have to go through each vertex and remove the weights from other bones.

Is there a way to group select the vertices and mass remove weights from all unwanted bones?

Comment: Use the tab key to bounce back and forth to edit mode. Verts selected in edit mode remain selected in weight paint, and vice versa. Also, verts hidden in edit mode are hidden in weight paint (vert) mode as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly assign and remove weights in edit mode, using the buttons in the properties window.

[image]